# How do I increase the performance of MSMQ Receive() without using multiple threads

Tags: msmq

**I am not able to use parallel threads in my application(C# Application) as each msmq msg is a data for sql statement**

**The C# Application consumes messages in the msmq , then processes it.**

I am using msg.Recoverable=true, to prevent data loss when server powers down.
Currently, it is transactional message.

**The msmq messages(sql statements) must be processed in order in the sequence(FIFO)**

Using multiple threads to consume is a no-no as unable to control which thread will consume and perform which sql statement.

Currently , the speed of Receive() for a msmq message of 490 KB is about 0.016 -0.032 sec, which makes about 30-50 Tx/sec, which is unacceptable.

**Currently, MSMQ receive is the bottleneck of the whole application**

Server is on Windows Server 2008 R2

and the application is getting(Receive()) from the Local server MSMQ, not remote

Comment: Post code. How do you process the SQL statements?

Comment: First I do a Peek, then perform sql statement, if sql statement performed successfully, I do a Receive(). Currently, Peek() takes 0 sec, sql statement performed takes 0 sec, Receive() takes 0.016sec-0.032sec. Obviously, for sql statements, they have to be performed FIFO,(For update statements)

Comment: Code is already optimized to the max, currently the question is how to further improve the performance of MSMQ Receive()

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, but i think you can try to use batching - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788973.aspx

Comment: The link i provided is about using WCF with MSMQ, but i think batching is possible with direct MSMQ API too.

Comment: don't understand how to use batching for a C# console application, is there other ways I can increase its performance other than changing code?

Comment: currently using non-transactional queues, and using a string to throw into msg.Body instead of Object, Receive() improved to 100 Transactions/sec. How can I further improve the performance of Receive()? How can I change these properties http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms705262(v=vs.85).aspx in my C# console application

Answer (score 0):

This blog discusses creating multiple "QueuePeekCompleted" event handlers.  It worked for me.

http://code-ronin.blogspot.com/2008/09/msmq-transactional-message-processing.html